# Using SQLite NOT %LIKE% and return all rows, even if value is NULL

Tags: sqlite

I have a column in my database called LABELS (value like business, personal, taxable ..). The field may contain 1 or more labels, or it could be blank.

When trying to use the statement `SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE (LABELS NOT LIKE '%Business%' )`, It returns all rows that don't contain Business, but it does NOT return any of the rows where there is no value in LABELS. How can I get it to return any row that does not contain business including the rows that have no value in LABELS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `LABELS` is `null`:

```
WHERE (LABELS NOT LIKE '%Business%' ) OR (LABELS IS NULL)
```

or with `COALESCE()`:

```
WHERE (COALESCE(LABELS, '') NOT LIKE '%Business%' )
```